# Resolving Python Symbols with Wildcard Imports using python-lsp-server

Tags: python, import, language-server-protocol, python-language-server, pylsp

I've been using the `python-lsp-server` to analyze a Python project and extract symbol definitions and references. The server works well for explicit imports, but I've encountered an issue when dealing with wildcard imports (`import *`).

Example:

Consider the following code structure:

```
# utils.py
def check_files_in_directory():
    pass
```

```
# main.py
from utils import *

def main():
    check_files_in_directory()
```

When I try to resolve the `check_files_in_directory` function in `main.py` using the LSP server, it fails to determine its origin due to the wildcard import.

What I've tried:

1. I've successfully resolved symbols for explicit imports, e.g., `from utils import check_files_in_directory`.
2. I've checked the LSP server's capabilities and ensured I'm sending the correct requests.

Question:

Is there a way to make python-lsp-server resolve symbols imported with wildcard imports effectively? **Do I have to set some configuration? For my case, even if it takes time or slow to resolve it, that is not a problem.**

Wildcard imports can be challenging for static analysis tools since they obfuscate the origin of symbols. I'm looking for a solution that can handle this scenario, whether it's a configuration or a combination of strategies.